# Form factor of ATX expansion slots

Tags: atx, expansion-cards, form-factor

I am building my own computer case, but I am having difficulty finding the form factor specifications for the ATX expansion slots - in particular the maximum height of the slot and the spacing of the screws, as in this image:

[image]

The closest I can find it the ATX2.2 specification on form factors.org, [here](http://www.formfactors.org/developer%5Cspecs%5Catx2_2.pdf).